# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Let $\alpha\in\operatorname{End}(\textsf{V})$. Then the following conditions are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I would appreciate assistance on the following question posed in an exam paper.

> Let $\textsf{V}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $\alpha\in\operatorname{End}(\textsf{V})$. Then prove that the following conditions are equivalent : 
>   $$\begin{align}
> (1) &\quad \textsf{V} = \ker(\alpha)\oplus\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \\
> (2) &\quad \operatorname{im}(\alpha) = \operatorname{im}(\alpha^2) \\
> (3) &\quad \ker(\alpha) = \ker(\alpha^2)
> \end{align}$$

The solution is given as:

(1)$\Leftrightarrow(2):\;\;  V\;=\;$ker($\alpha$)$\; \oplus\; $im($\alpha$)$\;\Leftrightarrow\;$ ker($\alpha$)$\;\cap\;$im($\alpha$) = {0}

$\Leftrightarrow\; \alpha|im(\alpha):im(\alpha)\rightarrow im$($\alpha^{2})\;\subseteq \;im(\alpha$) is one to one..................(A)

$\Leftrightarrow \;$ im($\alpha)\;=\;\;$im($\alpha^{2}$).

I do not understand line (A), specifically the first part of line (A) and why is it a one to one transformation?

Likewise, the second part of the proof states that:

(2)$\Leftrightarrow(3):\;\;$ since $dim(V)\;=\;dim(im(\alpha))+dim(ker(\alpha))$
 and$dim(V)\;=\;dim(im(\alpha^{2}))+dim(ker(\alpha^{2}))$,
then

$im(\alpha)=im(\alpha^{2})\;
\Leftrightarrow\; dim(im(\alpha))\;=\;dim(im(\alpha^{2})),\;$ since $\;im(\alpha^{2}) \subseteq im(\alpha)$............(B)

$\Leftrightarrow\;\; dim(ker(\alpha))\;=\;dim(ker(\alpha^{2}))$

$\Leftrightarrow\;\; ker(\alpha)\;=\;ker(\alpha^{2})$, since $ker(\alpha)\;\subseteq\;ker(\alpha^{2})$............(C)

I also do not understand the second part of equations (B) and (C), i.e. why is $\;im(\alpha^{2}) \subseteq im(\alpha)$ and $\;ker(\alpha)\;\subseteq\;ker(\alpha^{2})$

Thank you for your patience with this old lady.

Comment: You almost certainly copied the question incorrectly.  Given the solution, it seems as though the question was "prove that the following conditions are equivalent"

Comment: Also, you say "I would appreciate assistance".  Could you be more specific? Do you have trouble understanding the question? Do you have trouble understanding the proof?  Are you looking for an alternate proof?

Comment: I appreciate your comment and update. Yes, I did copy question incorrectly: thank you for correction. Also, my apologises for delayed response; I was incapacitated for the past week. And further, a part of the text of my original question seems to have disappeared.

Comment: No problem.  Now what about my second comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand line (A), specifically the first part of line (A) and why is it a one to one transformation?

Recall that $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) = \{\alpha(v) : v \in \mathsf V\}$, and $\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}$ denotes the restriction of $\alpha$ to the image of $\alpha$.  Now, note that
$$
\operatorname{im}(\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}) = \{\alpha(w): w \in \operatorname{im}(\alpha)\} = 
\{\alpha(\alpha(v)): v \in \mathsf V\} = 
\{\alpha^2(v): v \in \mathsf V\} = \operatorname{im}(\alpha^2). \tag{$\star$}
$$
That is, $\operatorname{im}(\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)})$ is the same set as $\operatorname{im}(\alpha^2)$.  So, we may think of $\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}$ as a map (in fact an onto map) from $\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$ to $\operatorname{im}(\alpha^2)$, and we see that $\operatorname{im}(\alpha^2)$ is indeed a subspace of $\operatorname{im}(\alpha)$.

Now, $\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}$ will be one to one if and only if its kernel is trivial, but what does the kernel of this map look like?  Note that
$$
\ker(\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}) = \{w \in \operatorname{im}(\alpha) : \alpha(w) = 0\} = \{w \in \mathsf V: w \in \operatorname{im}(\alpha) \text{ and } w \in \ker(\alpha)\} = \operatorname{im}(\alpha) \cap \ker(\alpha).
$$
That is, $\ker(\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}) = \operatorname{im}(\alpha) \cap \ker(\alpha)$.  So, $\alpha|_{\operatorname{im}(\alpha)}$ will be one to one if and only if its kernel is trivial, which is to say that $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \cap \ker(\alpha) = \{0\}$.  That explains line (A) and its equivalence to the line before.

> I also do not understand the second part of equations (B) and (C), i.e. why is $\;im(\alpha^{2}) \subseteq im(\alpha)$ and $\;ker(\alpha)\;\subseteq\;ker(\alpha^{2})$

I have stated above that $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(\alpha^2)$, but let's make this relationship more explicit.  As I say in the equations marked $(\star)$ above, we have
$$
\operatorname{im}(\alpha^2) = \{\alpha(w) : w \in \operatorname{im}(\alpha)\}.
$$
Because $\alpha: \mathsf V \to \mathsf V$, we have $\operatorname{im}(\alpha) \subseteq \mathsf V$.  Thus, it is clear that we have
$$
\operatorname{im}(\alpha^2) = \{\alpha(w) : w \in \operatorname{im}(\alpha)\} \subseteq \{\alpha(w) : w \in \mathsf V\} = \operatorname{im}(\alpha).
$$
We can argue that $\ker(\alpha) \subset \ker(\alpha^2)$ by noting that we have $v \in \ker(\alpha) \implies v \in \ker(\alpha^2)$.  In particular, if $v \in \ker(\alpha)$, then $\alpha(v) = 0$.  It follows that
$$
\alpha^2(v) = \alpha(\alpha(v)) = \alpha(0) = 0.
$$